# Tag Manager sales tracking for a price comparator

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

I have been having a hard time while trying to sort out a problem on Tag Manager. I would be so grateful if you could help me, I am totally lost.

I have to implement a sales tracking tag for a prices comparator website we want to be referenced in.

I found the tag tracking pattern provided by the company, however, I do not manage to get the same result. This the tag available on the website that I am asked to implement :

```
var _kkstrack = {
      merchantInfo : [{ country:"COUNTRY_CODE", merchantId:"COMID_VALUE" }],
      orderValue: 'ORDER_VALUE',
      orderId: 'ORDER_ID',
      basket:  [{ productname: 'PRODUCT1_NAME',
                 productid: 'PRODUCT1_ID',
                 quantity: 'PRODUCT1_QUANTITY',
                 price: 'PRODUCT1_PRICE'
                },
                { productname: 'PRODUCT2_NAME',
                 productid: 'PRODUCT2_ID',
                 quantity: 'PRODUCT2_QUANTITY',
                 price: 'PRODUCT2_PRICE'
                }
               ]
    };
    (function() {
      var s = document.createElement('script');
      s.type = 'text/javascript';
      s.async = true;
      s.src = 'https://s.kk-resources.com/ks.js';
      var x = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
      x.parentNode.insertBefore(s, x);
    })();
```

I implemented this tag, I created my variables that were based on my datalayer that is to say : "ecommerce.purchase.products.0.id" for example for productid. 
However, it did not work, I mean I got duplication, for 2 different products ordered, I ended up having the same title, id for both. The 2nd item had the same features as the first.

So I tried a 2nd solution :
For each variable I used custom Javascript (Kelkoo - purchase corresponds to a datalayer variable "ecommerce.purchase" ) This is what I wrote :

```
function() {
  var products = {{Kelkoo - purchase}};
 return products.map(function(prod) { return prod.price; });
}
```

Unfortunately, another problem has arisen : I got all the products datas next to each other separated by a coma (productid : 34756, 8546) Like below :

```
 basket:  [{ productname: 'PRODUCT1_NAME', 'PRODUCT2_NAME',
             productid: 'PRODUCT1_ID', 'PRODUCT2_ID',
             quantity: 'PRODUCT1_QUANTITY', 'PRODUCT2_QUANTITY',
             price: 'PRODUCT1_PRICE','PRODUCT2_PRICE'
            }
           ]
};
```

I would like to return the datas following this format

```
 basket:  [{ productname: 'PRODUCT1_NAME',
             productid: 'PRODUCT1_ID',
             quantity: 'PRODUCT1_QUANTITY',
             price: 'PRODUCT1_PRICE'
            },
            { productname: 'PRODUCT2_NAME',
             productid: 'PRODUCT2_ID',
             quantity: 'PRODUCT2_QUANTITY',
             price: 'PRODUCT2_PRICE'
            }
           ]
```

How can I do, do I have to build an array  ?

I thank you for your attention on this matter.

Thanks

Comment: Can you be more clear on what you're trying to track? Is the end goal events in GA? eCommerce transactions in GA? Enhanced eCommerce in GA?

Comment: Sorry for not specifying that, I am beginner so it did not came to my mind : it is on enhanced ecommerce

Comment: The products variable is already an array of objects. You just need to include that as part of the json that's pushed to ecommerce. I don't think you need to build anything special.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand, you already have a dataLayer with product data, that is matching the required content and data structure of Enhanced Ecommerce for Google Analytics. You would like to transform the product data into the format used in the `basket` key of `_kkstrack` variable.

Based on the Enhanced Ecommerce [Developer guide](https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/enhanced-ecommerce#purchases), enhanced ecommerce purchase data has the following format.

```
dataLayer.push({
  'ecommerce': {
    'purchase': {
      'actionField': {
        'id': 'T12345',                         // Transaction ID. Required for purchases and refunds.
        'affiliation': 'Online Store',
        'revenue': '35.43',                     // Total transaction value (incl. tax and shipping)
        'tax':'4.90',
        'shipping': '5.99',
        'coupon': 'SUMMER_SALE'
      },
      'products': [{                            // List of productFieldObjects.
        'name': 'Triblend Android T-Shirt',     // Name or ID is required.
        'id': '12345',
        'price': '15.25',
        'brand': 'Google',
        'category': 'Apparel',
        'variant': 'Gray',
        'quantity': 1,
        'coupon': ''                            // Optional fields may be omitted or set to empty string.
       },
       {
        'name': 'Donut Friday Scented T-Shirt',
        'id': '67890',
        'price': '33.75',
        'brand': 'Google',
        'category': 'Apparel',
        'variant': 'Black',
        'quantity': 1
       }]
    }
  }
});
```

You have several options to reference this data, either by pointing the whole ecommerce object to a dataLayer variable in GTM (and later referencing its keys in your code), or pointing directly to product arrays. (I'm using this latter so dataLayer variable name will be `ecommerce.purchase.products`)

Assigning products to {{DLV - Ecommerce purchase products}} GTM variable name, you can create a custom JavaScript function to make the necessary transformations.

```
function() {
  return {{DLV - Ecommerce purchase products}}.map(function(e) {
    return {
      productname: e.name,
      productid: e.id,
      quantity: e.quantity,
      price: e.price      
    };
  });
}
```

In your function you loop through all the product array elements, and return existing data under different keys, which is requested by this other tool. You can now use this custom JavaScript variable in your Custom HTML tag, where you set the content of `basket` variable.

Obviously, you can use your own variable naming convention, as long as you refer it in you custom JavaScript variable.

I hope I understood your question well, and you can solve your task with this answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it really helped me, I was struggling and now I see clearer, I made an attempt and it worked